# How to protect sensitive routes in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

so i'm building a node js application that runs express js and I set up a route like this, in app.js:

```
router.get("/db/:dbName", (req, res) => {
            var dbName = req.params.dbName
            if (dbName) {
                var coll = db.collection(dbName);
                coll.find().toArray()
                    .then(results => {
                        res.send(results);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.error(err)
                    })
            } else {
                console.log("put a dbName")
            }

        })
```

What is does is that on the click of a button it reads from a mongodb database and outputs the documents in the "dbName" collection.
I then had the idea to go to a seperate tab and type in "localhost:3000/db/collection" and of course it still works without the button (i.e it returns all documents in the collection).
My question is, what would be a way to prevent this behaviour, essentially only making the route accessible if you use the button.

Comment: You should use middleware for that. Check this [link](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).

Comment: You should make use of "session" and protect your APIs by using session variables.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a middleware and look for a value which is passed by only clicking the button. If that values is not passed to the server you can check for it and accordingly take action

```js
function middleware(req, res, next) {
 if(req.value) {
   next()  
 } else {
   return "Some error"
 }
}

app.route('/route', middleware, function(req, res) {})
```

For further check https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html